# Usage of readLine predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, nlp

In "Representation and Inference for Natural Language - A First Course in Computational Semantics" by Blackburn and Bos they give the following predicate:

```
parse :- 
    readLine(Sentence),
    s(LambdaExpression,Sentence,[]),
    betaConvert(LambdaExpression,Formula),
    printRepresentation(Formula).
```

It is supposed to initiate process of parsing sentence and creating semantic representation. I am omitting all other definitions, as believe they are irrelevant for my question. I am curios how to use this predicate `parse`

I tried `parse([Bob, walks])`, but got error message.

How do you think this `parse` should be used?

Comment: You just call it with `parse.` there are no arguments here. The `readLine` is a predicate that will query for input.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, but where I submit sentence that I need to parse `[Bob, walks]`

Comment: as far as I know, the `readLine` will likely prompt you for input.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so I just type `parse.` enter and then I can type `[Bob, walks]`. Do you know what is analog of readLine in SWI-prolog?

Comment: Try `read_string(user, "\n", "\r", _, String),`

Comment: @GuyCoder, Thank you, you gave correct reference to the book. I am simply reading it myself. Page 50 is correct page. I am going to try your suggestion on `read_string`.  I made a compromise while stating the question trying to avoid making it too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usage of readLine predicate in Prolog

Readline is a separate module that needs to be included with the code that uses readline, e.g.

```
:- use_module(readLine,[readLine/1]).
```

The file is named `readline.pl`

> How do you think this parse should be used?

There is also a separate test file. I would look at those.

---

From comment:

> Do you know where I can find readline module in SWI-Prolog?

The noted `readline` is not in SWI-Prolog it is part of the accompanying source code for the book.

There are two versions of the book and each version has similar but different code. Both versions of the code are available for free download from this course page at Ohio State.

Book 1 Code ([BB1](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/comsem/download/bb1.tar.gz))
Book 2 code ([BB2](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/comsem/download/bb2.tar.gz))

For "Representation and Inference for Natural Language - A First Course in Computational Semantics" there is a book [page](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/comsem/book2.html) and separate [page](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/comsem/software1.html) with links to the source code.

One version of the book can be downloaded as a [PDF](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/publikationen/softcopies/Blackburn:1997:RIN.pdf).

---

The code is designed to work on Linux. If you are using Windows and want to use the code I would stay away from Cygwin and instead [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) WSL ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)) which will give you a Linux shell, I use ([Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab)). Then in the Linux shell install SWI-Prolog ([PPA](http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/PPA.txt)) followed by the source code for the book.

Note: I regularly use WSL and use SWI-Prolog on WSL. I have not tried using the books code on this so I can't say it will work, but it is the same course of action I would take if I wanted to use the source code along with the book.

Comment: Do you know where I can find `readline` module in SWI-Prolog? Is this the one: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=readline

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I am now struggling to find definition of `printRepresentation`. In code for the book there is file `comsemPredicates`, it contains `printRepresentations`. I changed from single to plural, but still parse with `[mia, snorts]` return `fail` and I do not know how to troubleshoot, since `trace` is not working with `readLine`. Althrough `betaConvert` works perfectly

Comment: I appreciate that you are asking me, however I am too busy to try and look into this at present. I would suggest you post it as a new question and give details. I still have to check the validity of a recent answer given to one of my questions from a few weeks back. You should also note that the code is designed to run on Linux and what OS you are using. If using Windows then  note how you are getting it to run on Windows.